# Deserialization of Sets / Lists from JSON using Jackson and Spring 3.0 fails

Tags: json, hibernate, spring, jackson

I'm having a trouble desirializing POJO objects that contains sets

e.g.

```
class C {
    Set<SomeObject> set;
    ...
}
```

Using Jackson 1.8 auto mapping, I get all properties correctly, but if I use a set I get this

> org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException:
>   Unexpected token (START_OBJECT),
>   expected VALUE_STRING: need JSON
>   String that contains type id (for
>   subtype of java.util.Set)

Any Ideas what I'm doing wrong? is Generics in type / type erasure is the culprit? how do I fix it then?

Disclaimer, I'm using Hibernate persistent entities when I'm serializing and deserializing is out of session

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Structure of JSON data differs from structure of POJO; if you can include JSON here it should be easy to figure out where exactly mismatch occurs. Sets should be handled just fine, but they need to match with JSON arrays.